# How many incoming buffers for a networking application?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, networking

I'm writing a networking application which receives data from multiple clients: when a packet is received, the application reads and modifies the header, and then forwards the packet to one or more clients. I thought to use an output queue for each connection to a client, so the application is able to monitor the filling level of each output queue and detect the load on each client.

The routing of incoming packets could be achieved by a single thread, which should analyze the header of each packet in order to determine the destination client: this thread also accesses to a routing table in order to forward packets correctly.

How to handle incoming messages?
I could use a single shared queue or one input queue for each connection:

1. if I use *a single shared queue*, it would be concurrently accessed by the routing thread and by the threads that handle the connections with clients;
2. if I use *one input queue for each input connection*, it would be concurrently accessed by the routing thread and by the only thread which handles that connection from the client.

In the first case, the role of routing thread would be rather simple, since it should only dequeue the next packet from the queue and forward it to another client. In the second case, instead, the routing thread should check, one by one, all the input queues. This second approach could have the advantage of avoiding the fastest connections can fill the shared queue, thus increasing the probability that the other connections can find the queue full.

The second approach would require that the routing thread should follow a policy that ensures a fair behavior in relation to the input queues. What policy could be used in this case?

Moreover, what other reasons might lead one to choose the first or the second solution? What are advantages and disadvantages for both solutions?

Answer (score 1):

> The routing of incoming packets could be achieved by a single thread

Why have a thread at all? Why not just have a *method*, that is called by the receiving threads, that puts the result message on the write queue for the target client(s)?